# node.js: take input from file using readline and process I/O in windows command prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, cmd, pipeline

I want to run name.js file from the command prompt using **node.js** and pass the input file and redirect that output in output.txt,
I am writing a command for this is `node name.js < input.txt | > output.txt` but this is not working or I am wrong.

name.js look like this:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
var _line = "";
rl.on('line', function(line){
    _line += line;
});
rl.on('pause', function(_line){
    console.log(_line);
});
```

I have also tried this in `Powershell -Command "command"`

**EDIT**:
for example input.txt contain

```
hello js
hello node
hello world!
```

now,if i run `node name.js < input.txt > output.txt`.
i just get return value of *console.log()'s* "**undefined**" in output.txt

Comment: A friend of mine wrote a package that helps with this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell

Comment: The pipeline operator is used to transfer data to another process, but you only have once process, I can't see why you even need it.

Comment: About your edit, `undefined` is just what your program prints. You can check that by running it while omitting redirections altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing *_line* to rl.on('pause',function(*_line*){} hide the global *_line* that's why it's giving undefined and cmd command is fine.

there is other way to do this by using **process I/O** of node.js

```
function YourData(input) {
} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   YourData(_input);
});
```

read more about [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline) and [process I/O](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)